# How to generate migration file in typeorm using nest js

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger, nestjs-config, nestjs-jwt, nestjs-gateways

I am new this framework Nest JS and created sample Restful API but could not migrate the entity file. I tried many ways it's not working. first time run migration command to generate migration file it's working fine. but second time creating a new entity then run the migration command it's show no changes message how to fix this Issue.

**DB config .ts file**

```
{
            type: 'postgres',
            host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
            port: parseInt(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT) || 5432,
            database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
            username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
            password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
            entities: ["dist/**/*.entity{ .ts,.js}"],
            synchronize: true,
            "migrations": ["dist/migrations/*{.ts,.js}"],
            "migrationsTableName": "migrations_typeorm",
            // ssl:{
            //     rejectUnauthorized:false
            // }
          }
```

**Migration Command**

**Create and generate migration command**

```
npx typeorm migration:create -n User -d src/migrations

npx typeorm migration:generate -n User -d src/migrations
```

**Run Migration File**

```
npx typeorm migration:run
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `migration:generate` in your case. This will check your current database structure and compare it against entity file and based on this generate a new migration file with changes.

Problem that you were experiencing was porbably due to override.

`migration:create` will generate a new empty file and you run `migration:generate` it will not overwrite that file.

In case you want to write your own migration you can use `migration:create` as a simple and easy way to name it and structure it automatically.

Edit:

Also make sure to set `synchronize` to false as it will automatically migrate your data based on entities and changes otherwise.

I always turn this feature off and generate or write migration manually as it gives the most control.